# Where do I input the base class header for two derived headers?

Tags: c++, header, base-class

Tried reading other questions' answers, but none of them did it for me.

```
//Equipment.h
#pragma once
class Equipment {
//...
};
```

```
//Display.h
#pragma once
class Display :public Equipment { //here is the error
public:
    Display(int id, int price, int year);
};
```

```
//Display.cpp
#pragma once
#include "Display.h"
#include "Equipment.h"
Display::Display(int id=0, int price=0, int year=0) {
    int arr[3 + 1] = { id, price, year };
    //Equipment(int id, int price, int year);
}
```

```
//Printer.h and .cpp are very similar
//in composition to Display.h and .cpp
//error is in a similar position too
```

```
//source.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Printer.cpp"
#include "Display.cpp"
```

I don't really know where to place the `Equipment.h` base class include file. Tried putting it in source and thought it would work if I put it in first, nope.

Tried putting the include file in both derived headers, a different error pertaining to "already defined in Display.obj" appeared.

The header and cpp files all have to exist and I have no idea how I should place the include files.

Comment: Basic rule of thumb: only compile cpp files, only include hpp files.

Comment: @cigien The task rule was I had to add "Display.cpp" and "Printer.cpp" for declared member implementation. So I thought this was the way to go. Any other way I can do this without including cpp then?

Comment: Including in the header is the correct solution. You have some issue with your equipment header which is preventing that from working. Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at where the error occurred (the line with `//here is the error`), the compiler has not "seen" the `Equipment` class yet when it tries to compile `Display.h`. You can solve this error by `#include`-ing `Equipment.h` in `Display.h`.

As mentioned in one of the comments, you should avoid `#include`-ing `.cpp` files in your code. Source files should be compiled and then linked.

Answer (score 1):

Equipment.h

```
#pragma once
class Equipment {
    //,,,
};
```

Display.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Equipment.h"
class Display :public Equipment {
public:
    Display(int id, int price, int year);
};
```

Printer.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Equipment.h"
class Printer : public Equipment {
    Printer();
};
```

Display.cpp

```
#include "Display.h"
Display::Display(int id=0, int price=0, int year=0) {
    int arr[3 + 1] = { id, price, year };
    //Equipment(int id, int price, int year);
}
```

Printer.cpp

```
#include "Printer.h"
Printer::Printer() {
    //...
}
```

source.cpp

```
#include "Printer.h"
#include "Display.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//use Printer and Display
```